# Objective-C: Could I 'watch' a variable with code, so that the instant it changes I can change it back?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

There's a BOOL value that's part of an iOS UIKit object that I want to keep set as NO. Some user actions change the state of this, which I can't do anything about.

Is there a way to use the objective-c runtime to 'watch' this variable, and stop the change as soon as it occurs?

Comment: What class, what property, what goal? You should not be doing this, I'm sure there'd be a better solution if you told us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Could run a timer at say every 1/30th of a second to inspect it and then set it back if changed, but as @H2CO3 has said, generally this doesn't sound like a very good way of overriding this behaviour.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm more interested in whether it's possible to set some sort of variable 'watch' in objective-c. Like you say, there's another way of doing it (that has it's downsides) - so if it's possible to do what I'm asking it would make for a nicer solution.

Comment: @Jordan It is, key-value observing is what you are looking for, but still.

Comment: @Luke a timer would add a bit of overhead, good idea though. Also, it would probably be alright but just incase, it should probably be a way that responds the instant the property is changed, not 1/30th of a second later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

KVO supports the notion of property change listeners.

Here's the documentation: [KVO Compliance Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html)